# Wifi problem - drops randomly 20.04.3

Tags: networking, wireless

My WiFi connection drops at random times. Just upgraded from 18.10 to 20.04.3. Problem was not present in 18.10. Using a WiFi USB dongle, the drop occurred frequently, necessitating a re-boot to reconnect. I pursued some of the advice posted - stopped power-related screen blank which made 0 improvement. I now use an Ethernet connection from a nearby mesh router. That works ok for about 24 hours (I just started to note the time of day when it fails to see if there is a definite periodicity to the failure), and the connection can easily be restored by turning off the connection and re-connecting it. No reboot needed. There is no indication that the network connection has failed in the network tool. Any constructive ideas would b most helpful.

Comment: Look at the logs! `sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: Thanks.  what I saw was the wired connection was put own and then up by user request, every 24 hours.  the system requested an ip by dhcp just before the time the system dropped, and the server responded with an ip and a lease time of 24 hours.  so, i used the ubuntu network tool to change to a manual assignment, and to an ip that is in the reserved list on the router.  I had to ipconfig down the interface, and assign the ip with ipconfig.  ip  is now in the reserved address range. Many thanks for the advice.  I suspect this will fix it!